# find which control submitted the form in javascript

Tags: javascript, webforms, submit

HI guys,

is there any way to find which control is submitting the form through JavaScript??

also if one defined a JavaScript function to be called on the form submit event is there a way to find the control which caused the submission

Thanks a lot

Comment: In my case i have written a function for form submit in javascript and i needed to find which control did the submission...i need to do the work before postback...any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this can only be achieved by adding an event handler to each submit button. For example:

```
function () {
  this.form.submission_trigger = this;
};
```

Comment: this is the element firing the event, form is the form to which that form control belongs, submission_trigger is an arbitrary property of that form which you create. You can then read it in the form's submit event handler.

Answer (score 0):

on the server side if you have this you can see all infromation which user submit on the page include control

Answer (score 0):

On the client side?

With firebug you can.

You would have to overwrite the onsubmit event with : `console.trace`

So you would have to enter `document.getElementById("FORMID").onsubmit=console.trace`